# How to perform an SQL update using TADOCommand?

Tags: crud, delphi-7, ado

I want to create an update button using `TADOCommand` which is on a `TDataModule`, but this code doesn't work. Does anyone know what the correct code is?

[image]

Comment: What "doesn't work" for you exactly? Are you getting a compiler error? A runtime error? Noting updated in the DB? Please be more specific.

Comment: the update query is error and I don't know how to write the correct update query. that "update elektronik set ... where... is error. how to edit table with multiple fields in delphi 7?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Code is text, and can be directly copied and pasted into your post. Also, *doesn't work* is meaningless as a problem description. In what specific way does it not work?

Comment: oh yeah, I just found the problem. thank you so much !!

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL is malformed, as you are missing commas between the fields:

```sql
UPDATE Elektronik SET Nama_Barang = :Nama_Barang, Harga = :Harga, Stok = :Stok WHERE ID = :ID
```